# find a special patern in colume of mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to find one or two first number of string number, in column number, in mongodb. But when use a command...

> Blockquote 
>   db.rs1.find( { mob: { $regex: /^98/} } )

...in mongodb, it's give a limit number of column.  What is solution of problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please ask your question clearly

Comment: i have a many data in mongdb. the mongo data base have many column of data Contains of id , user name and mobile number . i want to query in mobile number column from mongodb that i want to find ( 09 ) and (9) number in First number in each feild of mobile number column . i use from >>>db.rs1.find( { mobile number : { $regex: /^98/} } )<<<  command for this work but did not give a correct answer . how to solution in broblem ?